# Why IQueryable executes in Where clause?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have

```
public IQueryable<Guid> AccessibleCities
{
    get
    {
        return CityRepository
            .FindAll(a => <CONDITIONS>);
    }
}
```

`CityRepository.FindAll` is implemented as:

```
public virtual IQueryable<TLookup> FindAll(Expression<Func<TLookup, bool>> predicate)
{
  return DataContext.GetSet<TLookup>().Where(predicate);
}
```

And I call this

```
anotherRepository
    .FindAll(a => AccessibleCities.Any(b => ANOTHER CONDITION));
```

When I call the last one, it generates two queries instead of adding AccessibleCities as query.

Please help me :)

Comment: Just simple condition:
CityRepository.FindAll(a => a.Id == 'GUID');

Comment: FindAll it is the same as Where in my case

Comment: public virtual IQueryable<TLookup> FindAll(Expression<Func<TLookup, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return DataContext.GetSet<TLookup>().Where(predicate);
        }

Comment: Maybe I should use Expression from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.aspx
?

Comment: Why would you expect that final query to add to your original one? Perhaps you need PredicateBuilder: http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx.

Comment: Yeah.. I think you are right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your final query just doesn't work that way; it doesn't concatenate by default.

Try the [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) class. That looks like it should work for what you're trying to achieve.